# Form posts data twice

Tags: php, jquery, form-submit

I have a feedback form in a pop-up div that otherwise works fine but processes SQL twice when the form results in error at first instance.

This is the html form:

```
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
    <form id="form" method="post" name="form">
        <p>Report:
            <select id="fbtype" name="fbtype"> 
            <option>Bug</option>
            <option>Suggestion</option>
            <option>Discontentment</option>
            <option>Appreciation</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>Brief description:
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="45" rows="10"></textarea>
        </p>
        <span class="error" style="display:none">Please describe your feedback.</span>
        <span class="success" style="display:none">We would like to thank you for your valuable input.</span>
   <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit" onclick="feedback_form_submit()"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

The feedback_form_submit() function is:

```
function feedback_form_submit() {
$(function() {
$(".submit").click(function() {
var fbtype = $("#fbtype").val();
var comments = $("#comments").val();
var dataString = 'fbtype='+ fbtype + '&comments=' + comments;

if(fbtype=='' || comments=='' )
    {
    $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
    $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
    }
    else
    {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "processfeedback.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(){
    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
    }
    });
    }
return false;
});
});
```

}

And the processfeedback.php has:

```
include "./include/session_check.php";
include_once "./include/connect_to_mysql.php";

if (isset($_POST['fbtype'])){

$userid =$_SESSION['id'];
$fbtype=$_POST['fbtype'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO feedback (userid, type, comments) 
    VALUES('$userid','$fbtype','$comments')") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Could anyone figure out why does the form submits twice? And any suggestion to control this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

If this is actually the code you're using, you seem to have wrapped your **onclick** function around the **$.click** event-adding function:

```
function feedback_form_submit() {
    $(function() {

        //  This adds a click handler each time you run feedback_form_submit():
        $(".submit").click(function() {

            // ... //

            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

When I tried this on jsFiddle.net, I clicked Submit the first time and nothing happened, then the second time it posted twice, the third click posted three times, etc.

You should just keep it simple: take out the **onclick** attribute:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit" />
```

and remove the feedback_form_submit() wrapper:

```
$(function() {

    $(".submit").click(function() {

        // ... //

        return false;
    });
});
```

This way the **$.click** handler function will be applied just once, when the page loads, and will only run once when *Submit* is clicked.

**EDIT:**

If your form is loaded via AJAX in a popup DIV, you have two options:

Keep your **onclick** but remove the **$.click** wrapper instead:

```
function feedback_form_submit() {

    // ... //

}
```

and

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit" onclick="feedback_form_submit()" />
```

Note that you only need to return false if you're using **<input type="submit" ... >**; when using **<input type="button" ... >**, the browser does not watch the return value of **onclick** to determine whether to post the form or not. (The return value may affect event propagation of the click, however ...).

Alternatively, you can use jQuery's **$.live** function:

```
$(function() {
    $('.submit').live('click',function() {

        // ... //

    });
});
```

and

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit" />
```

This has the effect of watching for new DOM elements as they are added dynamically; in your case, new **class="submit"** elements.

Comment: You may also want to use $('.error').fadeIn(200).show() at the top of your if {} else {} statement, rather than fadeOut(200).

Comment: I need to keep the onClick() as explained in comment to Phil, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Your feedback_form_submit function doesn't return false and on submit click you're also posting to the server. There is no need to have onClick in:

```
 <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit" onclick="feedback_form_submit()"/>
```

Change that to:

```
 <input type="button" value="Submit" class="submit"/>
```

And change your code to:

```
// Update: Since you're loading via AJAX, bind it in the success function of the
// AJAX request.

// Let's make a function that handles what should happen when the popup div is rendered
function renderPopupDiv() {
    // Bind a handler to submit's click event
    $(".submit").click(function(event) {
        var fbtype = $("#fbtype").val();
        var comments = $("#comments").val();
        var dataString = 'fbtype='+ fbtype + '&comments=' + comments;

        if(fbtype=='' || comments=='' )
        {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "processfeedback.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(){
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

// This is the success function for the AJAX request that loads the popup div
success: function() {
    ... 
    // Run our "onRender" function
    renderPopupDiv();
}
```

Comment: @saber, how is the popup div loaded? Did you mean to say that the DIV contents are loaded via AJAX? When I do "pop-up" DIVs (via a Fancybox Lightbox), I just embed them in the page and set `display: none` on a wrapper div, but if you're loading it via AJAX, the solution will be different.

Comment: Popup div is loaded via AJAX!

Comment: @saber, I've updated my answer to show that you should bind it in the success handler of the AJAX request that loads the popup div.